# Opencv imread JPG with alpha channel set to opaque(1/255)

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there an easier way to add an alpha channel to a `cv::Mat` read with `cv::imread` other than using `cv::merge` ?

This is what I'm using now:

```cpp
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("img_name.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    
std::vector<cv::Mat> matChannels;
cv::split(inputImage, matChannels);
    
cv::Mat alpha(inputImage.rows, inputImage.cols, CV_8UC1);
alpha = cv::Scalar(255);
matChannels.push_back(alpha);
    
cv::merge(matChannels, inputImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole conversion can be done in one line:

```
cv::cvtColor(inputImage, inputImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
```

all values of added alpha channel will be set to 255 according to [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_gray).